# Mathematical Formulation - No number less than Supremum M can be an upper bound

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, supremum-and-infimum, upper-lower-bounds

I was reading up on supremum and infimum and came across a line whose mathematical formulation has confused me. It says, **"No number less than the supremum, M of a set S can be an upper bound of S."** This line is very clear. Since M is itself the smallest member of the set of all upper bounds of S, this line is only obvious. But I am confused with the mathematical formulation that follows -

For any positive number , epsilon, however small, there exists a y belonging to S such that
**y > M - epsilon**

Can someone help me with this?

Attaching an image of it as well.[image]

Answer (score 1):

If there were no $y$ in $S$ such that $y>M-\varepsilon$, y.e. if $y\le M-\varepsilon$ for all $y\in S$, $M-\varepsilon$ would be a smaller upper bound.

Comment: what do you mean by 'smaller lower bound' here? we are talking about the supremum M here. Couldn't get what you are trying to say

Comment: I think you meant, if there were y belonging to S such that y < M-epsilon, then M-epsilon would be a smaller upper bound than M and thus it would be a supremum. Did i catch what u were trying to say?

Comment: @RandomlyReal There can be no upper bound that is smaller than the sup

Comment: @RandomlyReal: Yes, sorry for the *lapsus calmi* – I was thinking of two things at a time. It's fixed.